# Search file name under root url instead of file system

Tags: java

I have the following code which searches file name under filesystem

```
 private String getFile(final String myId) {

    File folder = new File(System.getenv("MY_DIR"));

    return folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
            return name.startsWith(myId);
        }
    })[0].getName();
}
```

How do i modify to look under http://server.com/mydir instead of /home/jay/mydir which is MY_DIR currently?

Comment: Not sure you can do that this way. Are you trying to implement an FTP client?

Comment: what kind of service is available at that URL? Is it WebDAV, a regular Apache directory listing or something else?